# set answer options and answers in vba chart

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I am creating charts using vba. For that I am using the following code:

```
Function CreateChart(start, finish, chartPos) As Integer
    Dim objChart As ChartObject
  Dim myChtRange As Range
  Dim myDataRange As Range
  Dim seri As Series
  With Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Charts")

    ' What range should chart cover
    'Set myChtRange = Application.InputBox( _
        prompt:="Select a range where the chart should appear.", _
        Title:="Select Chart Position", Type:=8)
    ' What range contains data for chart
    Set myChtRange = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Range("A" & chartPos & ":F" & chartPos + 19)
    'Set myDataRange = Application.InputBox( _
        prompt:="Select a range containing the chart data.", _
        Title:="Select Chart Data", Type:=8)
    Set myDataRange = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidation").Range("A" & start - 1 & ":B" & finish - 1)
    ' Cover chart range with chart
    Set objChart = .ChartObjects.Add( _
        Left:=myChtRange.Left, Top:=myChtRange.Top, _
        Width:=myChtRange.Width, Height:=myChtRange.Height)
    ' Put all the right stuff in the chart
    With objChart.Chart
        .ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = False
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SetSourceData myDataRange
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.text = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidation").Range("B" & start - 1).Value
        .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
        .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 18
    End With
    If Not cType = "Round" Then
        objChart.Chart.Legend.Delete
    End If
    If cType = "Points" Then
        objChart.Chart.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowLabel
    End If
    Set seri = objChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    If Not cType = "Points" Then
        seri.HasDataLabels = True
    End If
  End With
  CreateChart = chartPos + 25
End Function
```

"start" and "finish" are the rows that the table starts and finishes and they have always 2 columns (A, the value and B, how many times) In most of the times it works perfectly. For example for this table it gives this chart:

[image]

But if the possible values is a number it makes it wrong as you can see in this example:

[image]

It takes the possible answers as result. If find the way to change it to behave correctly clicking with the right button and selecting charType but not with vba and I want to correct it with vba. Is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to change it to a string "1","2" etc...-?
I don't know how that would affect your chart since I don't use them often...

.NumberFormat = "@"